# loading image from documents directory without knowing image name

Tags: xcode, uiimage

I am having some set of images in my documents directory.
but I don't know the names of those images.
as those are directly downloaded forms server and saved in directory path.

what I am getting is Path for that image along with image name attached in last.

I tried to use`imageWithContentsOfFile` but of no use.

I also searched in all possible ways, but failed.

Can any one help me out for getting only image name out from that path.
here is my code.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"Here my documents directory path"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you maybe want firstly the list of images (or other files) that you have in the directory. And then you can load it.
For having a list of file names of a directory (in a `NSArray` in this case) try:

```
NSArray *fileNames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath error:nil];
```

Then you can load the image, by the way you were trying, with the full path string.
Sorry for my english if it's not correct,
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Javito, it works. applied for loop over array to set images over buttons. as I wanted to. thanks